# Reinstall update-manager in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, update-manager, wayland

#### Summary

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Recently while trying to install a game using Lutris, I managed to remove ubuntu desktop from my computer. I managed to reinstall wayland using `sudo apt install gnome-session-wayland`. Now my computer works normally apart from minor changes on my desktop. But I realized that update-manager is missing. I don't receive any updates and I cannot upgrade my OS to Ubuntu 22.10. I need help with reinstalling `update-manager`

#### More context on how I messed up my setup

I was following [these instructions](https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md). Due to some mistakes, I wanted to start over and I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove -y nvidia-driver-515 libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
sudo apt remove libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*
```

After that I started getting problems with `lightdm` during reboot and the OS failed to load the UI. I got around the issue by installing wayland via:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-wayland
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall update-manager` would do that ... Although `lightdm` tells me you are running an Ubuntu flavor or you have changed the default GDM.

Comment: Stop using `-y` with apt commands. It disables a key protection, as you discovered to your sorrow. ALWAYS read and understand your apt output before agreeing to changes. That output is there to protect your system. Use it!

Comment: Inspect the log files in `/var/log/apt/`. That's where package installs and uninstalls are logged.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^`. This will restore all the default packages ubuntu-desktop comes with

Comment: @Raffa 's comment worked. Thank you.

Comment: Also, thanks @ArchismanPanigrahi I've reinstalled the ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Now that you found the solution, can you write your own answer for future users?